# How to print a message in the console when the user inputs a negative number in assembly

Tags: assembly, mips, mars-simulator

I am starting with assembly language and I want to print a message in the console if the user inputs a negative number.

My code:

```
.globl  main

.data
# program output text constants
prompt:
.asciiz "Please enter a positive integer: "

.text

main:
    li      $v0,    4                   # issue prompt
    la      $a0,    prompt
    syscall 

    li      $v0,    5                   # get input from the user
    syscall 

    blt     $v0,    $zero,      main    # input must be positive

    # rest of the code that's executed when the input is positive
```

From what I know, I can compare between two values and go to a specific target in my code, which in this case, I used `blt`: "branch less than", which checks if the input by the user `$v0` is less than `0` or not, if it is less than `0`, the code starts reading from `main` again.

The output of this code:

```
Please enter a positive integer: -2
Please enter a positive integer: -3
Please enter a positive integer:
```

I was able to achieve the looping of the input prompt whenever the user inputs a negative value but I also want to print an error message to the console. How can I do that?

Comment: You know how to print a string, so the question is where you could put a block of code to do that only before retrying, not on the first prompt.  (Or to update a pointer in a register so instead of just a prompt, you print an error message + prompt after the first iteration).

Comment: There are multiple ways you could go about this, like jumping over the block on success vs. falling into it and having it end with an unconditional branch back to the top of the loop.  Or jumping up earlier than the loop entry point, to some extra code before `main:`  (You might need a `j main` before that if your simulator starts execution at the top of the .text section, not at `main:`.)

Comment: Note that `0` is non-negative but also not positive either.  You claim you want to require a positive number, but you're only retrying on negative, not also zero.  `blez $v0, main` would do that.  (MIPS compares other than eq / ne are one register against 0, not two registers against each other.  `blt $reg, $reg, target` is a pseudo-instruction that has to use `slt`, unless you're using an assembler smart enough to optimize to `bltz` when one reg is `$zero`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [Peter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/224132/peter-cordes)'s first comment, this does ring a bell. I would like to print the error prompt only when  the input is less than zero. The second comment is a bit difficult to understand at my current knowledge of assembly language, but I came up with a solution of using a function for this. Simplifying my question, I want to perform two tasks, first one is printing an error message to the console and the second one is starting the code from `main`. I put the code to do both of them inside a function

```
func:
    li      $v0,    4
    la      $a0,    "Error: Invalid input"
    syscall 

    b       main
```

and call it whenever the user inputs a negative number

```
main:
    li      $v0,    4                   # issue prompt
    la      $a0,    prompt
    syscall 

    li      $v0,    5                   # get n from user
    syscall 

    blez    $v0,    func                # n must be positive
```

Also thanks again for your third comment, I did realize now a mistake I was making, I wasn't checking if the user inputs `0` or not.

Comment: `blez` doesn't pass a return address, so your `func` isn't actually a separate *function*, just a block with a label.  (Which I assume prints an error message then jumps to `main`.)  I guess you could look at it as a tailcall to a function that tailcalls main, but really the same logic would work even if `$ra` wasn't valid at that point.  And yes, that's probably the best way to do it, so the correct-input case just falls straight through, with the error-handling code somewhere else.  (Smaller I-cache footprint for the common case fast path, if this was on a real CPU.)

Comment: @PeterCordes could you please write an answer on what your idea is?

Comment: I'm not suggesting a different idea, I'm saying your way of doing it is good, just pick a name other than `func` because it's not really a function.  It's part of `main` that you're just putting somewhere else, perhaps after the `jr $ra` or exit system call at the bottom of main.

Answer (score 0):

You must take advantage of the `bltz` instruction to achieve this. Check if the user's input is less than 0, then branch to a label in the code that prints the error message if it is a negative number that was entered. Then the prompt to input a new number should appear.

Comment: `bltz` is the instruction that jumps on strictly less than 0.

Comment: @PeterCordes It actually branches and doesn't "jump" hence the name "branch less than zero". To jump, you would either use `j`,`jr`, or `jal` depending on the type of jump you want to do.

Comment: In computer architecture in general, branch and jump are basically synonyms.  I was just describing when the conditional branch is taken.  But yes, fair point that MIPS distinguishes those, with branches being relative and jumps being section-absolute.

Comment: @PeterCordes Yes, but considering the person who asked this question is new to the MIPS Assembly language, it would be more appropriate to use the proper terminology so as to not confuse them or anyone else who would find this thread informative.